# Endless progressbar?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

I am trying to download a file with Indy but the file is served by a PHP script so it does not have any Content-Length specified. Therefore I cannot set Progressbar.Max. I saw Windows has some nice endless progressbars- is such thing available in Delphi?

Comment: If you're downloading small files (for small amount of time waiting) I would suggest using a spinner animation for feedback, but if your download take something longer than 30 seconds, even if you don't know the total size, I strongly recommend adding some feedback of the downloaded data, something like `Downloaded Bytes: ####` and update every second, so the user will know that the download still going and is not stuck even if they don't know the remainder time it take.

Comment: @Vitim.us Thanks. It should help me finding the best approach for this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set to a common [`TProgressBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar) control the [`Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar.Style) property to [`pbstMarquee`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar.Style).

Comment: Thanks, it is in XE2 just wasn't in D7 which I know much better.

Comment: +1. In earlier versions of Delphi, you can send the [PBM_SETMARQUEE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the `TProgressBar.Handle`. (Works on XP and above.) You might want to add that to your answer since there wasn't a version-specific tag to the question.